# Converting DOCX to PDF with PHPWord and DomPDF

Tags: php, pdf, docx, dompdf, phpword

I'm running a web only server (So no server access and no things like Composer or LibreOffice) and I want to convert a DOCX template to PDF. I have succesfully processed my template with PHPWord (Downloaded using php-download.com since I can't use composer), everything fine there, but when I try to use DomPDF (also downloaded through phpdownload) to convert my docx file to a PDF file, PHP throws me "Class 'Dompdf\Dompdf' not found"...

I created a seperate file to just convert an already known docx file just to exclude any environmental issues

This is my code:

```
require_once("includes/PHPWord/vendor/autoload.php");

$inputfile = "files/temp/offerte_Hankie-Pankie.docx";

$path = realpath(realpath(__DIR__) . '/includes/dompdf');

echo "realpath: " . $path;

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($path);
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF);

//Load temp file
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($inputfile); 

//Save it
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('result.pdf');
```

Using the echo I confirmed the folder is set properly: "/home/myusername/domains/mydomain.nl/public_html/projects/pdftemplate/includes/dompdf"

So i tried parsing the subfolders "src" or "lib" without success, I tried parsing the actual autoloader file "autoload.inc.php" and didn't work either. I tried all of the above paths with and without ending "/" (Just to be sure) and still class not found... Even though I'm using exact copies of code found to be (presumably) working on the internet.

I tried finding it in the PHPWord documentation, which didn't give me any solutions. I also tried excluding PHPWord and just using DomPDF, but since DomPDF only accepts html as input, and I don't know how (And didn't want spend another hour trying that) to convert docx to HTML, this was also a dead end.

Just as a reference, here is my file structure:

- Work dir

  - CodeIsInThisFile.php
  - includes

    - dompdf
    - lib
    - src

      - Autoloader.php
    - autoloader.inc.php
    - PHPWord
    - vendor

      - autoload.php

So either I messed something up in my file structure because of the manual downloads (Which seems the most likely to me), or my code is wrong (Also likely)...

Comment: It may be helpful to include the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

First download the dompdf library using composer or using git.
Use the `realpath()` or try to use the absolute path for PDF rendering library.